# How to create custom attribute for post in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, servlet-filters

I need some custom attributes for post in wordpress, I am create a filter functionality and when any type keyword related post attributes then all post will show automatically.

Any one idea about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as I understood, you want to add some custom fieds to your posts. Thus, you could check the custom "**Custom Fields**" that could be found in "**Screen Options**" tab on the right up corner (while you are editing a post).

[image]

[image]

After that, you will see at the bottom of the post the "**Custom Fields Tab**".
[image]

Metadata is handled with key/value pairs. The key is the name of the metadata element. Thus, the **name** is the **key** and the **value** is actually the ****value** of the key** you just enter.

Finally, inside your post template file, you could call all these custom fields. The most used functions are:

`the_meta():` shows the list of custom fields in the front-end in an unordered list.
`get_post_meta( $post_id, $key, $single ):` gets the value of a custom field.

Comment: Ok Thank you, Your support, I think I have to install a plugin custom fields

Comment: It is not necessary for a plugin with the method I mentioned about, but of course you could use a plugin like ACF